# Dynamic form not sending all values

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

I have a form and I can add more dynamically by using Javascript, and that is working; but when I send the value to the controller I only get the data from the last filled form and have no idea why.
I am using laravel 5.4.

I'm putting the whole view code just in case there is something I am not seeing and maybe someone else will.

```
    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'items.store', 'method' => 'POST'), array('role' => 'form')) !!}
    <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more"  id="formulario">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('cantidad[]', 'Cantidad') !!}
      {!! Form::text('cantidad[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'Ingresa cantidad del item', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('detalle[]', 'Detalle') !!}
      {!! Form::text('detalle[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'Ingresa detalle del artículo', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('unidad[]', 'Unidad') !!}
      {!! Form::text('unidad[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'Ingresa la unidad de medida (cm, m, kg; etc)', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('unitario[]', 'Unitario') !!}
      {!! Form::text('unitario[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'Indica el valor unitario del item', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    {!! Form::button('Guardar', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}   
    {!! Form::close() !!}

     <div class="form-group hide" id="cloneMe">
      <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('cantidad', 'Cantidad') !!}
      {!! Form::text('cantidad', null, array('placeholder' => 'Ingresa cantidad 
    del item', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('detalle', 'Detalle') !!}
      {!! Form::text('detalle', null, array('placeholder' => 'Ingresa detalle del artículo', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('unidad', 'Unidad') !!}
      {!! Form::text('unidad', null, array('placeholder' => 'Ingresa la unidad de medida (cm, m, kg; etc)', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('unitario', 'Unitario') !!}
      {!! Form::text('unitario', null, array('placeholder' => 'Indica el valor unitario del item', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" value="borrame">Borrar</button>
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#formulario"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#botoncito"); //Add button ID
   
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            var cloneHtml = $('#cloneMe').html();
            $(wrapper).append(cloneHtml); //add input box
        }
    });
   
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: How about you share some code? We can't solve the problems we can't see. Where do you preform the form submission?

Comment: I was trying to add the code and my internet conection died :'(

Comment: Seems #formulario is not closed
#cloneme is not closed too.
In your cloneme container the fields have the same name as the other, but not as array... i think so it posts only the last ones.

Comment: It is closed, right after the submit button.
Please correct me if i'm wrong, but i thought that the clone me should have the same name given it is the same form basically, but not an array since is a single one (?)